Why is accessing random indices in an array n-times slower than accessing them in order in C?
Consider the following code:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    int n = 1000000000;

    int *a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        int r = rand() % n;

        a[r] = r;
    }

    free(a);
}

When simply compiled with gcc test.c, it runs (according to time ./a.out) in 42 seconds on my machine. When I change a[r] = r to a[i] = r, it is much faster and takes only 15 seconds on my machine. Why does accessing random indices in the array take so much more time than accessing them in order? I expected both to take the same time.

Caching. If you use sequential indexes most of the data will be in the CPU caches. If you use random indexes the CPU have to flush the cache and fetch new data from memory a lot more.

For sequential access just about all the data will be in cache memory before it is accessed and worst case there will be at most one cache miss every 64 bytes (16 ints). For random access the odds of a lucky cache hit are 16:10^9 - very low indeed and almost every access will be an L1 cache miss and flush.  It won't be quite as bad as that since the L2/3 multi level caches will fill up so that not everything will have to go to main ram for a data fetch but it will be substantially slower.

Also you appear to take the time of executing rand() into the benchmarking attempts. Like usual, "why is code x slow" can be explained by poor benchmarking before anything else. Did you even enable optimizations?
